# run a cmd in shell script for once

Tags: linux, redhat

a shell script runs 12 times in a day (in every 2 hrs). the script transfer data from location (/var/log/2015_07_29) to external storage (/data).

the script has a make directory command for date such as

a=`date +"%F"`
b=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f1`
c=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f2`
d=`echo $a | cut -d'-' -f3`
mkdir $d_$c_$b

But it has to be run only once because once it is created at first place, we don't need to run this command remaining 11 times.

Can you restrict this command to be run once in a day ?

Comment: where is the part which is count the runtimes ?!?!? did you use cronjob or s.th else?

Comment: I don't really get the question. mkdir only creates the folder if it does not already exists, so what is your problem? You can use mkdir -p to suppress the warning about an existing directory, and then you should be fine. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Exactly, everytime the script is called, it try to create a directory. and the when we do ls -lrth /directory, it will show last updated.

Comment: Shouldn't it be like, if directory exists no action, if it doesnt, create a new directory ?

Comment: @ErAB If that's what you want, then the answer I put should do it I think.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you just want to prevent the `mkdir` part being run if the directory is already there, just check that first.

```
[ -d $d_$c_$b ] || mkdir $d_$c_$b
```

The left side of the `||` is testing whether the directory exists.  If it does exist, the expression evaluates to true, so the right side is never evaluated. Otherwise, the right-side gets run, creating the directory.

Comment: that's not a answer, pls comment it such like improvements.

Comment: @FeritCubukcuoglu is that better?  I've added more explanation, hopefully that's what you meant.